# Laravel and Vue: How do I get images from my public folder in a Vue component?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to get a logo image from my public folder in my laravel and Vue application. The file is called `index.vue` and have the following structure:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="header-container">
            <div class="header-content">
                <div class="logo-container">
                    <img :src="'/public/images/logo/black.png'" alt="logo">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Tell Vue where to render components -->
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

Here is the file structure and you can see that file exists and the path is correct:

[image]

But when I switch back to the view it looks like this:

[image]

I have also tried to call it the way I would in a blade template using `{{ asset() }}`, but this doesn't work and gives me a compiler error.

How do I get this image to load in my Vue file?

Comment: Have you tried following the steps in the official documentation, assuming that you're running VueCLI? https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder

Comment: @Terry I am completely new to Vue.js so I'm not sure if I am running VueCLI, is there a way to check that I am?

Comment: If you're not using VueCLI, how are you building your site? There must be a build step you're running somewhere, I suppose, given that you're using `<template>` tags indicate that you're using single-file components, which necessitates some kind of bundler.

Comment: @Terry I created my project using Laravel and so I use `php artisan serve` to build and run my site

Comment: There's more than that. What kind of boilerplate are you using to integrate Vue in your laravel project? Laravel does not automagically include Vue in the standard setup.

Comment: @Terry I ran `php artisan ui vue` to install the vue that I needed

Comment: If that's the case, the `/public` folder should be root. This should work (without the need for binding): `<img src="/images/logo/black.png" alt="logo">`

Comment: @Terry THANK YOU! I've been trying everything and that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about vue + laravel. But, since its a relative path I dont think you need to bind anything.

```
    <img src="/images/logo/black.png" alt="logo">
```

Comment: that is giving me this error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './public/images/logo/black.png'

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer. I think you just need to remove public.

Comment: Yes thank you! That worked!